# How to change a kotlin private val using reflection?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, kotlin-reflect

I can access a private val value using reflection as below

```
fun main() {
    val mainClass = MainClass()
    val f = MainClass::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == "info" }
    f?.let {
        it.isAccessible = true
        val w = it.get(mainClass) as String
        println(w)
    }
}


class MainClass {
    private val info: String = "Hello"
}
```

But if I want to change `info`, how could I do it using reflection?

Comment: I will try to find an answer for you but I can't guarantee I will succeed.. Meanwhile it would be interesting to know why you want to do this? You probably know it is generally a bad idea to circumvent compile time checks in runtime.

Comment: Agree, it's bad thing to do. Just to see if there's a way to do it.

Answer (score 37):

### Answer

In short, you have to use Java reflection APIs in this case, and here is how to do it:

```
fun main() {
    val mainClass = MainClass()
    val f = MainClass::class.java.getDeclaredField("info")
    f.isAccessible = true
    f.set(mainClass, "set from reflection")
    mainClass.printInfo() // Prints "set from reflection"
}

class MainClass {
    private val info: String = "Hello"
    fun printInfo() = println(info)
}
```

### Reason for using Java reflection APIs

It is not possible to do with Kotlin reflection APIs since no setter code is generated for a read-only (`val`) property. So to change it, we need to use Java reflection APIs which is more low-level. First, we use **Tools** -> **Kotlin** -> **Show Kotlin Bytecode** to see what the generated bytecode looks like. Then we see this:

```
// ================MainClass.class =================
// class version 50.0 (50)
// access flags 0x31
public final class MainClass {
  // access flags 0x12
  private final Ljava/lang/String; info = "Hello"
  // ...
```

i.e that the `info` fields in the `MainClass` Kotlin class causes the compiler to emit JVM code for a regular `MainClass` Java class with a `final String info` field. So to change it, we can use Java reflection APIs, as in the code above.

### Kotlin reflection API attempt

If the field would have been `private var` you would be able to Use Kotlin reflection APIs like this:

```
f?.let {
    val mutableProp = it as KMutableProperty<*>
    it.isAccessible = true
    mutableProp.setter.call(mainClass, "set from Kotlin reflection")
    val w = it.get(mainClass) as String
    println(w)
}
```

but if you try this with `private val` you will get the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KProperty1Impl cannot be cast to class kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty (kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KProperty1Impl and kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at MainKt.main(main.kt:107)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt)
```

since no setter code is generated for `val` fields, and thus the `info` property will have a Kotlin Reflection API type of `KProperty` and not `KMutableProperty`.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. See if someone else could provide a val solution. If no, then this will be my ticked answer.

Comment: @Elye Maybe time to mark this answer as Accepted now? ;)

Answer (score -2):

**This is working solution**

```
import kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

class MySolution {

var name = ""
var email = ""
}

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun main() {

//Dummy Result Set
val rs = mapOf<String,String>("name" to "My Name", "email" to "My Email")

val mySol = MySolution();
val xyzMp = MySolution::class.memberProperties;
xyzMp.forEach { mp ->
   val prop =  mp as KMutableProperty<String>
    prop.setter.call(mySol, rs[mp.name])
}

println(mySol.name)
println(mySol.email)
println("*****Enjoy*******")
```

**output**

```
My Name
My Email
**** *Enjoy*******
```

Comment: This does not address the question asked. Your example demonstrates using kotlin.reflect to change a **public var**, but the question asks how to change a **private val**.  Enselic's answer also shows that kotlin.reflect cannot be used to do this.